Voiceover is not reading description (aria-describedby) of links
I have <a> tag in my code that has tooltip attached to it and tooltips are supposed to be read by aria-describedby. Voiceover on mac is just ignoring it and only announcing the link.

Associated WAI-ARIA roles, states, and properties
The element that serves as the tooltip container has role="tooltip" set.
The element that triggers the tooltip references the tooltip element with aria-describedby.

ARIA: tooltip role
But this same behaviour is also observed here in the sample code which I have taken from wcag. Here they assign aria-describedby to <a>
tags, and Voiceover does not read this as expected.
Using aria-describedby for link purpose
This works on windows with NVDA but when using voiceover on mac Safari or Chrome, the description is not announced.
If you change the <a> tag to <button> then it will work but it does not work if you assign <button> with role="link"
Please suggest any possible and accessible work-arounds to this issue.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <ul> 
      <li id="li1"> 
        Check out the video report for last year's 
        <a href="festival.htm" aria-describedby="li1">National Folk Festival</a>. 
      </li> 
      <li id="li2"> 
        <a href="listen.htm">Listen to the instruments</a> 
      </li> 
      <li id="li3"> 
        Guitar Man: George Golden talks about 
        <a href="mkguitars.htm" aria-describedby="li3">making guitars</a>. 
      </li> 
   </ul> 
</body>
</html>



Just a heads up, that second link is a page that hasn't been updated in over a decade.

Because the link element is described by its parent, it's therefore a circular reference that includes itself. This is likely why it's being ignored.
document.querySelector('li#li1').textContent;

// output 
// Check out the video report for last year's National Folk Festival.

I know that it's a W3C example you're following, but I don't think it's a good example. DOM nodes within a list item are already programmatically associated, and it's unnecessary to try to use ARIA to further link them together.
It's my understanding that aria-describedby is meant to reference a different DOM node (i.e. a sibling or child element) but not a parent.
From the aria-describedby spec:

The aria-labelledby attribute is similar to the aria-describedby in that both reference other elements to calculate a text alternative...

If you're trying to create tooltips, then an <a> element is not really semantically correct. Use a <button> instead if you are trying to create a trigger for displaying hidden text. The anchor element implies that the URI will change, which is typically not true for tooltips.
The tooltip pattern is generally used on interactive UI controls, like this:
<input aria-describedby="password-rules" id="password" type="password" />
<div id="password-rules">Passwords must contain a minimum of 8 characters.</div>

If your goal is to add additional advisory text to regular links, then another technique you might try is using screen reader only text, as derived from the bootstrap library.
